# CORS error from NextJS endpoint error even with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header

Tags: api, next.js, cors, authorization

I have a React frontend making a call to a NextJS endpoint. I have what I believe are the correct headers set on the server using the `next.config.js` file...

```
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    webpack: (config, options) => {
        if (!options.isServer) {
            config.resolve.fallback.fs = false
        }

        return config
    },
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/api/:path*',
                headers: [
                    { key: 'origins', value: '*' },
                    { key: 'Bypass-Tunnel-Reminder', value: '*' },
                    { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: '*' },
                    { key: 'Access-Control-Request-Methods', value: 'POST, GET, OPTIONS' },
                    { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', value: 'Authorization, Content-Type' },
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

Nevertheless, I keep getting a CORS error when I call the endpoint from my frontend.[image: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/api/github/setCredentials' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.]

Here is the frontend code...

```
axios.post(
                    'http://localhost:3001/github/setCredentials',
                    {
                        accessCode,
                    },
                    {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: localStorage.getItem('jwt_token'),
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        },
                    },
                )
```

The `jwt_token` looks like "Bearer <TOKEN>"

The endpoint looks like this...

```
const authenticate = (method, req, res) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        passport.authenticate(method, { session: false }, (error, token) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            } else {
                resolve(token)
            }
        })(req, res)
    })

passport.use(jwtStrategy)

const handler = nextConnect({
    onError: (err, req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse, next) => {
        console.error(err.stack)
        res.status(500).end('Something broke!')
    },
    onNoMatch: (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
        res.status(404).end('Page is not found')
    },
})
    .use(passport.initialize())
    .post(async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
        try {
            const user = await authenticate('jwt', req, res)
            if (!user) return res.status(403).json({ error: 'Unauthenticated user' })
            
            return res.status(200).json({ success: true })
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err.toString() })
        }
    })

export default handler
```

The passport.js authentication strategy looks like this...

```
const opts: any = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()
opts.secretOrKey = JWT_SECRET

export const jwtStrategy = new JwtStrategy(opts, function (jwt_payload, done) {
    mongoose
        .getUserByEthAddress(jwt_payload.address)
        .then((user: User | null) => {
            return done(null, user)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return done(err, false)
        })
})
```

Interestingly (frustratingly?) enough, hitting my other endpoints do not cause CORS errors. Also, when I remove the "Authorization" header from the request, I get a typical 403 error thrown by the middleware being unable to find the user, but no CORS error.

Also, when I make this call on Postman with the Authorization token and everything, it works great, so the auth layer is not the issue.

Any ideas what could be causing this? Everything I read makes it seem like setting the "Access-Control..." headers in the `next.config.js` file would solve this, but that has not been the case. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on from reading your code, but be aware that preflight requests do not cary any authentication information. If your authentication middleware stands in their way, CORS preflight will fail every single time. This is likely the problem, here. Instead of setting CORS headers manually, I recommend you find a good CORS middleware and put it in front of any authentication stuff.

Comment: Yep that was the trick! I'll post an answer with more details about the fix. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

@jub0bs led me to the fix. I needed to do a couple things.

1. Set up nextjs-cors middlware like so...

```
    .use(async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse, next) => {
        await NextCors(req, res, {
            // Options
            methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
            origin: '*',
            optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
        })
        next()
    })
```

2. Add an OPTIONS method to the handler...

```
    .options((req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
        return res.status(200).send('ok')
    })
```

Then, my passport middleware populated the request with a `req.user` object that I can use when I handle the POST method.